# Python 3 - Pandas - Missing Data and Binning Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data, binning

I have the below code which pulls data from a CSV file and I want to perform some analysis on one of the variables in the data set. The variable is an object data type and it has a lot of missing values. Therefore, I am using pd.to_numeric to transform them to NaN. Then I create some bins (1,2,3,4,5) to categorise the values of the variable.However, I would like to include NaN as a category or bin in the new variable ("variable_q"). For example as "No Data" category. Is that possible? How can I do that?Am I missing anything>

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

data["variable"]=pd.to_numeric(data["variable"],errors="coerce")

data["variable_q"]=pd.cut(x=data["variable"],bins=[1,2,3,4,5],labels=["Low","Moderate","High","Extremely High"])
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `data["variable_q"] = data["variable_q"].fillna('No Data')` after the cut?

Comment: I get the below error...
ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Comment: `data["variable_q"] = np.where(data["variable_q"].isna(), 'No Data', data["variable_q"].astype(str)`.

Comment: data["variable_q"] = np.where(data["variable_q"].isna(), 'No Data', data["variable_q"].astype(str))
ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am doing a frequency distribution on the variable and I just realised that adding dropna=False as an argument in the below code solves the problem.

A NaN category has been created!So there is no need to add a "No Data" category in the above code.

data["variable_q"].value_counts(sort=False,dropna=False)